# AWS RDS Aurora autoscaling with custom instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, autoscaling, amazon-aurora

Amazon RDS allows specifying an instance type when you manually add a reader replica. However, if I add a "replica auto scaling" rule, it inherits the instance type from the writer instance.

For example, I'd like to have my writer instance "db.r5.large" while all my reader instances being "db.t3.medium"s. The RDS GUI does not allow to select instance types while defining the auto scaling rule, unlike EC2. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: From the docs: "When Aurora Auto Scaling adds a new Aurora Replica, the new Aurora Replica is the same DB instance class as the one used by the primary instance." So it doesn't sound like it's possible. Plus if I'm not mistaken, in the event of a failure on the writer, a reader could become "promoted" to a writer. If it wasn't the same size/type, that could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible like 404 wrote in a comment.
This is the link to the official documentation:
[Using Amazon Aurora Auto Scaling with Aurora replicas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Integrating.AutoScaling.html)

> When Aurora Auto Scaling adds a new Aurora Replica, the new Aurora Replica is the same DB instance class as the one used by the primary instance